# Compiling DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I am trying to build DotNetOpenAuth and there are some build errors.  I am curious if those errors are actually generic.  I downloaded the code and it loads in VS.NET 2010 just fine except that in compilation it relies on GithubCommitId's.

The problem happens when this line is used in the build `script:+build.$(BuildNumber).$(GitCommitId.Substring(0,10))`

Here is the build log.

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Mono.Math, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AArnott-dotnetopenid-6c29eba\tools\DotNetOpenAuth.Versioning.targets(29,4): error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(0, 10)" cannot be evaluated. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
------ Rebuild All started: Project: DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AArnott-dotnetopenid-6c29eba\tools\DotNetOpenAuth.Versioning.targets(29,4): error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(0, 10)" cannot be evaluated. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Org.Mentalis.Security.Cryptography, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AArnott-dotnetopenid-6c29eba\tools\DotNetOpenAuth.Versioning.targets(29,4): error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(0, 10)" cannot be evaluated. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
------ Rebuild All started: Project: DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Common, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AArnott-dotnetopenid-6c29eba\tools\DotNetOpenAuth.Versioning.targets(29,4): error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(0, 10)" cannot be evaluated. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
------ Rebuild All started: Project: DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AArnott-dotnetopenid-6c29eba\tools\DotNetOpenAuth.Versioning.targets(29,4): error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(0, 10)" cannot be evaluated. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
------ Rebuild All started: Project: DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AArnott-dotnetopenid-6c29eba\tools\DotNetOpenAuth.Versioning.targets(29,4): error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(0, 10)" cannot be evaluated. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
------ Rebuild All started: Project: DotNetOpenAuth.InfoCard, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AArnott-dotnetopenid-6c29eba\tools\DotNetOpenAuth.Versioning.targets(29,4): error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(0, 10)" cannot be evaluated. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
------ Rebuild All started: Project: DotNetOpenAuth.Core.UI, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AArnott-dotnetopenid-6c29eba\tools\DotNetOpenAuth.Versioning.targets(29,4): error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(0, 10)" cannot be evaluated. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
------ Rebuild All started: Project: DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AArnott-dotnetopenid-6c29eba\tools\DotNetOpenAuth.Versioning.targets(29,4): error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(0, 10)" cannot be evaluated. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
------ Rebuild All started: Project: DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AArnott-dotnetopenid-6c29eba\tools\DotNetOpenAuth.Versioning.targets(29,4): error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(0, 10)" cannot be evaluated. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
------ Rebuild All started: Project: DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ServiceProvider, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AArnott-dotnetopenid-6c29eba\tools\DotNetOpenAuth.Versioning.targets(29,4): error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(0, 10)" cannot be evaluated. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
------ Rebuild All started: Project: DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationServer, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AArnott-dotnetopenid-6c29eba\tools\DotNetOpenAuth.Versioning.targets(29,4): error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(0, 10)" cannot be evaluated. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
------ Rebuild All started: Project: DotNetOpenAuth.InfoCard.UI, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AArnott-dotnetopenid-6c29eba\tools\DotNetOpenAuth.Versioning.targets(29,4): error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(0, 10)" cannot be evaluated. Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
------ Rebuild All started: Project: RelyingPartyDatabase, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
```

PS: this has been posted on GitHub as well as [issue #88](https://github.com/aarnott/dotnetopenid/issues/88).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Issue 88](https://github.com/aarnott/dotnetopenid/issues/88), the workaround is to download the source repository using git rather than as a .zip file.

The issue is still open, pending a fix to the build authoring so that it doesn't require git to be present.